# Ajax POST Form to Django Data Issue

Tags: ajax, django, forms, post, authentication

been frustrated with this for a couple days and was wondering if anyone could help. I'm new to Ajax and trying to post data from a login form in order to login to Django (Django Userena). However, when I try to post the data, alert() shows me the error in data as [object object]. I can't even see the network error code because the POST gets canceled before it can run.

Is there a way to just send the data and not the entire JSON array that I think its sending, or do I need to parse it out on the Django view backend. What is the best way to accomplish this code wise? Thank you very much!

Below is the relevant code:

**Ajax Code:**

```
$('#login').submit(function(){

    $.ajax({

        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signin/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
            identification: $("#id_identification").val(),
            password: $("#id_password").val(),
            },
        success: function() {
            alert('Test');
            $('#datadisplay').append("<h2>It worked</h2>");
        },  
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
            alert('Error');
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

**Form on Index.html**

```
<form name="login" id="login" action="">
   <fieldset>
           <label for="id_identification">Email or username</label>
           <input class="required" id="id_identification" maxlength="75" name="identification" type="text" />

           <label for="id_password">Password</label>
           <input class="required" id="id_password" name="password" type="password" />

           <input type="submit" name="submit" class="loginbutton" value="Login" />
       </fieldset>
   </form>
```

**views.py from Django-Userena**

```
@secure_required
def signin(request, auth_form=AuthenticationForm,
           template_name='userena/signin_form.html',
           redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
           redirect_signin_function=signin_redirect, extra_context=None):
    """
    Signin using email or username with password.

    Signs a user in by combining email/username with password. If the
    combination is correct and the user :func:`is_active` the
    :func:`redirect_signin_function` is called with the arguments
    ``REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME`` and an instance of the :class:`User` who is is
    trying the login. The returned value of the function will be the URL that
    is redirected to.

    A user can also select to be remembered for ``USERENA_REMEMBER_DAYS``.

    :param auth_form:
        Form to use for signing the user in. Defaults to the
        :class:`AuthenticationForm` supplied by userena.

    :param template_name:
        String defining the name of the template to use. Defaults to
        ``userena/signin_form.html``.

    :param redirect_field_name:
        Form field name which contains the value for a redirect to the
        succeeding page. Defaults to ``next`` and is set in
        ``REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME`` setting.

    :param redirect_signin_function:
        Function which handles the redirect. This functions gets the value of
        ``REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME`` and the :class:`User` who has logged in. It
        must return a string which specifies the URI to redirect to.

    :param extra_context:
        A dictionary containing extra variables that should be passed to the
        rendered template. The ``form`` key is always the ``auth_form``.

    **Context**

    ``form``
        Form used for authentication supplied by ``auth_form``.

    """
    form = auth_form()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = auth_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            #identification, password, remember_me = (form.cleaned_data['identification'],
                                                     #form.cleaned_data['password'],
                                                    #form.cleaned_data['remember_me'])
            identification, password = (form.cleaned_data['identification'], form.cleaned_data['password'])     

            user = authenticate(identification=identification,
                                password=password)
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                if remember_me:
                    request.session.set_expiry(userena_settings.USERENA_REMEMBER_ME_DAYS[1] * 86400)
                else: request.session.set_expiry(0)

                if userena_settings.USERENA_USE_MESSAGES:
                    messages.success(request, _('You have been signed in.'),
                                     fail_silently=True)

                # Whereto now?
                redirect_to = redirect_signin_function(
                    request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name), user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
            else:
                return redirect(reverse('userena_disabled',
                                        kwargs={'username': user.username}))

    if not extra_context: extra_context = dict()
    extra_context.update({
        'form': form,
        'next': request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name),
    })
    return ExtraContextTemplateView.as_view(template_name=template_name,
                                            extra_context=extra_context)(request)
```

**AuthenticationForm**

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    A custom form where the identification can be a e-mail address or username.

    """
    identification = identification_field_factory(_(u"Email or username"),
                                                  _(u"Either supply us with your email or username."))
    password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False))
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(),
                                     required=False,
                                     label=_(u'Remember me for %(days)s') % {'days': _(userena_settings.USERENA_REMEMBER_ME_DAYS[0])})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ A custom init because we need to change the label if no usernames is used """
        super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Dirty hack, somehow the label doesn't get translated without declaring
        # it again here.
        self.fields['remember_me'].label = _(u'Remember me for %(days)s') % {'days': _(userena_settings.USERENA_REMEMBER_ME_DAYS[0])}
        if userena_settings.USERENA_WITHOUT_USERNAMES:
            self.fields['identification'] = identification_field_factory(_(u"Email"),
                                                                         _(u"Please supply your email."))

    def clean(self):
        """
        Checks for the identification and password.

        If the combination can't be found will raise an invalid sign in error.

        """
        identification = self.cleaned_data.get('identification')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if identification and password:
            user = authenticate(identification=identification, password=password)
            if user is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_(u"Please enter a correct username or email and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive."))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: I don't see any code susceptible to POST a JSON array. What's the response code for the AJAX request ? Maybe `{{ csrf_token }}` is empty ?

Comment: You might try removing csrf verification temporarily, with @csrf_exempt, to see if there is another problem somewhere else too

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't get the response code because it exits in error before it completes. The console from the code above prints "Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, set RequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function...}" but once I close the last dialogue box it exits and clears the console.  

How would I put in csrf_token in the form when the form is not being displayed through Django but rather an external html form?

Comment: Ah how silly am I! That might be the issue, would you know off hand how to reference the form on my index.html page, if I need to, since it is outside Django View? Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 1):

These are the errors (not all and I think there are more) I see when I test your codes:

1. how can you login if you didn't use your AuthenticationForm() in your template. You form codes in the template is different.
2. you didn't put method="POST" in your form which result on GET response instead of POST.
3. you forgot to put {% csrf_token %} in your template form
4. In your views.py, **user = authenticate(identification=identification,  password=password)** must be **user = authenticate(username=identification, password=password)**
5. In your forms.py, **user = authenticate(identification=identification,  password=password)** must be **user = authenticate(username=identification, password=password)**
6. Your ajax codes has no effect that's why you can't get the error thrown. I think your missing something in your ajax.
7. To get the details of the error thrown:

   ```
   error: function(ts){
       //console.log(errorThrown);
       //alert('Error');
       alert(ts.responseText);
       }
   ```
8. your ajax data must have '':

   ```
   data: {
       'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
       'identification': $("#id_identification").val(),
       'password': $("#id_password").val(),
       },
   ```
9. You don't have to elaborate your url like this one

   ```
   url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signin/',
   ```

   It will result to

   ```
   "http://127.0.0.1:8000/http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signin/"
   ```

   It must be

   ```
   url: '/accounts/signin/',
   ```

   and don't also forget to put

   ```
   contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   ```

There are more errors and until now I can't successfully login.

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far. I'm working on this and it POSTs now with no error, but I don't think its doing anything and the page just refershes with no data sent. My goal is to make a mobile app with Django as the backend. With PhoneGap the front end needs to be HTML/CSS/JS **only** so no Django templates and also Django tags don't make sense. Do you know if there is an easier solution to my goal of getting users logged in/registering? I think TastyPie might be the direction to go, but I attempted that and couldn't figure it out either. Any insights would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know anything in mobile. I also never use TastyPie. If I can get an information I will tell you right away :)